SAP Crystal Reports 2020 quote database name in SQL query - syntax error
I'm running into an issue after upgrading from Crystal reports 2011 to the newer 2020 version, in which reports running against databases that have the "-" character in the name are failing with syntax errors, I've narrowed this down to the 2011 version quoting the database name and the 2020 version is not quoting the database name, causing the "-" to be treated as a separate command.
Show SQL query on CR2011 would be like
SELECT "something" FROM "my-database-1"."table" 

Whereas show SQL query on CR2020 would be like
SELECT something FROM my-database-1.table 

error check for the right syntax to use near '-database-1.table'
The database is being loaded from an ODBC source, which connects and tests fine, between the versions I have had to use a different driver due to CR2011 being 32bit and CR2020 being 64bit
CR2011 using MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode x86
CR2020 using MySQL ODBC 8.4 Unicode x64 (also tried 8.0 and 9.0)
I'm looking to enable the quotation of the database name but have been unable to find any way to enable it in Crystal reports gui, registry or in the ODBC connector settings.
I have tried the referenced double quotation registry key from the below link but not had any luck https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1217820

Perhaps you used the registry entry (IdentifierQuoted) in the wrong branch.
Since Crystal 2020 is 64-bit, you should use the branch without \Wow6432Node

I've tried adding this key you mentioned (IdentifierQuoted) but to no luck. I've been putting them in the branch without Wow6432Node already,  tried both user and system sections.
Filtering for DatabaseOptions in ProcessMonitor while the app loads, it never attempts to read from that reg key, but it does for almost everything else listed the linked article.
